# What do I upload when working with Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

This is the first time I've used Composer to work with dependencies for a PHP project. I basically have a project folder that has

APP folder (with a starter configuration file)
PUBLIC folder (with php and css files)
VENDOR folder (created by composer)
composer.json
composer.lock

The question is, what do I upload to my server in order to make the project live? I've read you shouldn't upload the vendor folder generated by composer, but not sure how it's supposed to work. They also mentioned you should run install but how is that done when the project is on the server and not local?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's good to let the vendor folder out of the VCS (git, svn) but, if you are deploying to a shared hosting, one of those annoying ones that doesn't let you have SSH access, in that case, yes you need to upload the vendor folder every time that you update composer in your project.

Answer (score 2):

Composer lets you manage the dependencies of your project. But first of all, are you building a application or a library? If it's a application, you should upload the composer.lock to your version control. If it's a library, you should not do it. **The vendor folder should never be part of your version control or uploaded to your server** ([find why here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md)).

Basically:

- Set the composer.json file, with all your dependencies, project name, description, etc.
- Install composer in your machine, [getcomposer.org](http://getcomposer.org) has great tutorials on how to do this. (Composer also has the composer.phar which is basically the composer app in a single file. Download it and use `php composer.phar [command...]` instead just composer).
- Inside the project root, run `composer install` (or `php composer.phar install` if you have the composer.phar in your project). All of your dependencies will be installed, generating the vendor folder and updating the composer.lock if it already exists or creating it if not.

The composer.lock tells you about each dependency in your project. That is why you put it in the version control of an application, because you want to run the same version of the dependencies on your local machine and on your server.

And you don't do this with libraries, because you don't know what other developers' dependencies will be when they use your library.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is the following:

1. ignore the vendor directory and composer.lock file
2. push the rest of your project up to the server
3. run composer self-update on the server first
4. after, run composer update.
5. now it's done

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. How do I run composer self-update on the server? What would my working folder be? Is this done through Terminal? Sorry, like I said, it's the first time I do this. Thanks again.

Comment: You will need to SSH into the server in order to use composer. if composer is not installed, you will need to download and install it on the server. your working folder will be the root directory of your site. for instance, on an debian environment, that's `/var/www/html`. inside of here, you will have your entire application. Your site will actually be accessed through `/var/www/html/public`, so you will need to modify your vhost entry to match this. you'll run `composer self-update` from the `/var/www/html` directory (just above the public).